# Installing PHP using Homebrew on Mac

Tags: php, macos, phpmyadmin, homebrew

I am trying to install PHP on my Mac machine using Homebrew.
I am using the following command:
`brew install php`

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "php" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

#### Update

In February 2018, the `php72` formula (the current version of PHP at that time) has been moved into the core Homebrew tap and renamed as `php`.

The `homebrew/php` tap [has been deprecated](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4721) in January 2018 and then archived on March 31, 2018. The formulas it contained are not available any more.

Since February 2018, installing PHP using Homebrew is as easy as:

```
$ brew install php
```

The older PHP versions [that are still maintained](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) can be installed using the new `@` convention for versions (PHP 7.1 is `php@7.1`).

---

#### The original answer (not usable any more)

The PHP ecosystem lives in the `homebrew/php` tap. You can find there six versions of the interpreter (from `5.3` to `7.1`), extensions for them and some PHP-related tools.

In order to install PHP you have to install the `homebrew/php` tap first (this is needed only once):

```
$ brew tap homebrew/php
$ brew install php70
```

Or you can do both operations in a single step by running:

```
$ brew install homebrew/php/php70
```

---

You could discover all these by searching `php` first:

```
$ brew search php
```

Comment: Update to the latest version: `$ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php` then `brew install php72`. Or you can check options how to install php72 `brew options php72`.

Comment: Also note with the March 2018 update, all the php-XXX extension modules are no longer in homebrew, you have to use pecl to install them. For me, I used to `brew install php72-yaml` now I have to `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net` followed by `pecl install yaml`. This might require you to install some build tools like autoconf as well if you don't already have them.

Comment: Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

Comment: Unless you need a specific version of PHP for matching your production environment, which is always a good idea, and most often a requirement in real life. What if you have several clients with different versions in production? Check out [phpenv](https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv) for that.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, I'm on Big Sur macOS 11.1

Answer (score 26):

After installing PHP with brew,

```
brew install php@7.3
```

or any version you need(could be: php@7.2)

run this command to ensure you have PHP installed: `brew list | grep php` then you need to manually add an alias as follows:

```
alias php='/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.13/bin/php'
```

Then, for the change to take effect you need to refresh your terminal. You can use: `source ~/.bash_profile` command, or close and open terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I thought the whole point of homebrew was to take care of these configuration tweaks...

Comment: @pixeline : It would be a nightmare for the developer (and OS) if tools that's already installed by macOS (like the php command) suddenly got swapped out with a different version.

**You should NOT use an alias as mentioned over!**
Specifying version numbers in an alias only works until the next minor version and what about the other tools that PHP needs from the `bin` directory? 
Use this at the end of your shell startup script instead:

`export PATH="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/php@7.3/bin:${PATH}"`
Then all commands for 7.3.x (not just `php`) is available and chosen first.

Comment: BTW! I've mapped the variable $HOMEBREW_PREFIX used in the comment above to the output of `eval $(brew --prefix)`, 
as in:
`export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="$(brew --prefix)"`
Good idea to mention This is usually `/usr/local` but mapping it to a variable makes it more portable.

Comment: additional : after put alias in bash_profile you might need to restart terminal. it works well.  and for the path you can search in your own because current php@7.3/7.xxxxxxxx/bin is not the same.

Comment: After running `brew install php@7.3` I get `Error: php@7.3 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula!`

Answer (score 25):

I ran into this error in 2021 using Mac OS Big Sur.
Running the below commands helped me out

1. `rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)`
2. `brew tap homebrew/core`
3. `brew install php`

[Link to source](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1512)

Comment: You made my day mate, yesterday my macos updated and PHP not working, now after spending more than 8 hours, my PHP got installed thank you so much

Comment: This solution worked for me (macOS Monterey)

Comment: This helped me so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can run

```
brew doctor
```

to see which branch is being used  for some reasons some of the formulas are not on the origin....so kindly checkout to master on brew

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

and then try to run

```
brew search php
```

to see if its listed

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.3
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.1
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.2
```

And switching with:

```
brew link --overwrite php@7.4
```