# Unable to find pcntl on homebrew in mac high sierra

Tags: php, macos-high-sierra, pcntl

I have been trying to install pcntl extension using homebrew in MacOS High sierra using command

```
brew install homebrew/php/php71-pcntl
brew install homebrew-php/php71-pcntl
```

Also tried with php54, 55, 56, 70
I m getting error

Updating Homebrew...

```
Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php7-pcntl" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/php is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/php)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
```

Why its not finding the formulae on my Mac I have php 7.1.14 on my mac

Comment: Also read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537955/installing-php-using-homebrew-on-mac/42538097#comment86373487_42538097) on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42537955/4265352).

Answer (score -2):

In February and March 2018 the PHP formulas for the [currently supported PHP versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) (5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 at the moment of this writing) were moved to the core Homebrew tap and in April 2018 the PHP tap has been archived.

To install the current PHP version (7.2) use:

```
$ brew install php
```

To install one of the other supported versions use:

```
$ brew install php@5.6
```

(replace `5.6` with `7.0` or `7.1` for the other versions).

All the formulas installed this way contain the `pcntl` extension, there is no need for anything else.

Comment: I already have 7.1 intalled and i just did brew update php@7.1 however there is still no pcntl extension there

Comment: I also already have installed  7.1.  No luck to find 'pcntl' :-(